# How do you custom configure RESTeasy for use with Mockito?

Tags: java, spring, jackson, mockito, resteasy

I'm trying to figure out how to configure RESTeasy for use with Mockito. I had to create custom Serializers and Deserializers. I found [this](http://blog.palominolabs.com/2012/06/05/writing-a-custom-jackson-serializer-and-deserializer/) article that talked about creating custom serializers and deserializers and turning them into a module.

I also found [this](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQJaxRs) article and [this](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Customizing-ObjectMapper-td6234597.html) article  about configuring Jackson to use the new custom module that I wrote.

The problem that I'm having is that I don't know how to test it. One of the articles says

> The answer is to have Jackson(Jaxb)JsonProvider in the resteasy.providers section of resteasy-jaxrs.war/WEB-INF/web.xml

I'm using Mockito to test everything. As far as I know, there isn't a resteasy-jaxrs.war file that is made. Is there anyway that I can fake this?

I should probably also add that I'm using spring and I have an applicationContext.xml file that I use just for creating fake beans etc. for testing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want unit tests REST application go with REST-assured. It is very simple and powerful library - you don't need to mock everything. For other options see [Ways to test RESTful services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165561/ways-to-test-restful-services).

Remember that even if you manage to mock everything, such test might be hardly useful - you'll test your mocks, not a true application.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I figured it out, I just didn't write up my response for this question.